# Redirect to different `index` file when API is in the URL with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling a lot trying to redirect API calls to a different index file.

I want to redirect all URL's that have `[domain-name]/API/*` in the URL to a different script: `API_index.php`.

I tried doing it with the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /API/
RewriteRule . API_index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(font-awesome|fonts|ajax|tools|log|documentation)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

According to [this website](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) this URL, http://abayocms.dev/API/test, should match, but I am still being navigated to index.php?

**ANSWER**

Apparently the .htaccess [L] only stops the current iteration over the URL.
Once I redirected to the API_index file with my first rewriteCond + Rule, the server starts a new iteration with the new URL, which would be `[some domain]/API_index.php`.

This gets catched by my last rule and still gets redirected to `index.php`

Thus this scenario needs its own rule:

```
RewriteRule ^API_index.php$ - [L]
```

---

The total file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Prevents redirecting API_index.php to index.php
RewriteRule ^API_index.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /API/
RewriteRule . API_index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(font-awesome|fonts|ajax|tools|log|documentation)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Big thanks to @starkeen for the answer!

Comment: Are there any other rules?

Comment: Nope, this is everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `/API_index.php` is matched by your 3rd rule and gets rewritten to `/index.php` .

You need to pass the `/API_index.php` untouched, try adding the following after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteRule ^API_index.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: But it should not get to the third rule right? Thats why I put [L] behind it. And I tried several positions of your rule, could you please put the entire .htaccess file in the solution to show me where to place it?

Comment: It is happening because of internal redirects, L doesnt do what you think it does, it stops  the current iteration only. for exaple `/API/` gets rewritten to `/API_index.php`   , in order to serve the `/API_index.php` Server reads the htaccess again, and this time the URI is matched by your last rule.

Comment: Aaaaah, thats how it works! Thank you for explaining it to me :D